# Whole parentNode with attributes for a specific comment with php DOM and xpath?

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I want to output parentNode of the comment  with attributes (ID or class)

If I have this html code

```
<div><span><!--test--></span><div class="myclass"><!--test_comment--></div></div>
```

I want the following output

```
<div class="myclass"><!--test_comment--></div>
```

If I have this html code

```
<div><span id="myid" style="color:blue;font-weight:bold"><!--test_comment--></span><div class="myclass"><!--test--></div></div>
```

I want the following output

```
<span id="myid" style="color:blue;font-weight:bold"><!--test_comment--></span>
```

This is my php DOM code with xpath

```
<?php
$html = <<<STR
    <div><span><!--test--></span><div class="myclass"><!--test_comment--></div></div> 
STR;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$node = $xpath->query('//comment()');

$myComment = $node->item(1)->textContent; // <!--test_comment-->
$myNode = $node->item(1)->parentNode->nodeName; // div

echo $node->item(1)->parentNode->nodeValue; //NOT WORKING

echo "<" . $myNode . ">" . $myComment . "</" . $myNode . ">";

?>
```

The problem is I do not know how to search a specific comment (). Would like to have something similar `$xpath->query('//comment() == "test_comment"');`

My php code results in

```
<div>test_comment</div>
```

How can I get the attributes (class or ID) inside the div? nodeValue is not working.

Also welcome any other comments on my code when I am newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML(data());

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$node = $xpath->query('//*[comment()]');
foreach( $node as $p ) {
    echo 'output: ', $dom->saveXML($p), "\r\n";
}


function data() {
    return <<< STR
<div><span id="myid" style="color:blue;font-weight:bold"><!--test--></span><p>no comment here</p><div class="myclass"><!--test_comment--></div></div> 
STR;
}
```

prints

```
output: <span id="myid" style="color:blue;font-weight:bold"><!--test--></span>
output: <div class="myclass"><!--test_comment--></div>
```